# I try to make the buton green if answer corect and red if it is wron then somehow reset the graphics to default

Tags: java, android, button

I try to make the buton green if answer corect and red if it is wrong then somehow reset the graphics to default state.I have tried to put the R.drawable code in diffrent places and none of them work, and on top of that i think i have to add a sleep timer for the effect to be visible? I am convinced i just put the code in the wrong place beacause i think it should work using this code. Please somebody enlighten me :)

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.Random;


public class Game extends AppCompatActivity {



    AdView adView;
    Button ans1_btn, ans2_btn, ans3_btn, ans4_btn, back_btn;
    TextView  question, score;
    private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private DatabaseReference myRef;
    String userId;

    private Questions mQuestions = new Questions();
    Random r;
    private String mAnswer;
    private int mQuestionsLength = mQuestions.mQuestions.length;

    int uScore;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

        //Initiate
               r = new Random();
          adView = findViewById(R.id.add);
        ans1_btn = findViewById(R.id.ans1_btn);
        ans2_btn = findViewById(R.id.ans2_btn);
        ans3_btn = findViewById(R.id.ans3_btn);
        ans4_btn = findViewById(R.id.ans4_btn);

        back_btn = findViewById(R.id.back_btn);

        question = findViewById(R.id.question);
        score    = findViewById(R.id.score);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        myRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference();
        final FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        assert user != null;
        userId = user.getUid();





        myRef.child("users").child(userId).child("eScore").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                uScore = dataSnapshot.getValue(Integer.class);
                score.setText(String.valueOf(uScore));
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


        //...//



        // update question randomizer
          updateQuestion(r.nextInt(mQuestionsLength));
         //...//

        //Button Functions

        ans1_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (ans1_btn.getText() == mAnswer){
                    uScore+=10;
                    Toast.makeText(Game.this,"Corect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    score.setText("Score: "+ String.valueOf(uScore));
                    myRef.child("users").child(userId).child("eScore").setValue(uScore);
                    ans1_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.corect_btn);
                    resetButtons();
                    updateQuestion(r.nextInt(mQuestionsLength));

                }else
                    gameOver();



            }
        });

        ans2_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (ans2_btn.getText() == mAnswer){
                    Toast.makeText(Game.this,"Corect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    uScore+=10;
                    score.setText("Score: "+ String.valueOf(uScore));
                    myRef.child("users").child(userId).child("eScore").setValue(uScore);
                    ans2_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.corect_btn);
                    resetButtons();
                    updateQuestion(r.nextInt(mQuestionsLength));

                }else
                    gameOver();


            }

        });
        ans3_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (ans3_btn.getText() == mAnswer){
                    Toast.makeText(Game.this,"Corect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    uScore+=10;
                    score.setText("Score: "+ String.valueOf(uScore));
                    myRef.child("users").child(userId).child("eScore").setValue(uScore);
                    ans3_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.corect_btn);
                    resetButtons();
                    updateQuestion(r.nextInt(mQuestionsLength));


            }else
                gameOver();


            }
        });
        ans4_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (ans4_btn.getText() == mAnswer){
                    Toast.makeText(Game.this,"Corect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    uScore+=10;
                    score.setText("Score: "+ String.valueOf(uScore));
                    myRef.child("users").child(userId).child("eScore").setValue(uScore);
                    ans1_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.corect_btn);
                    resetButtons();
                    updateQuestion(r.nextInt(mQuestionsLength));


                }else
                    gameOver();




            }
        });

        back_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Game.this,Home.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });



        //...//



        // Full Screen
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
        //.....//
        // AdMob add - Banner
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                .build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        //...//


    }

    // Update Question Function
        private void updateQuestion(int num){
        question.setText(mQuestions.getQuestions(num));
        ans1_btn.setText(mQuestions.getChoice1(num));
        ans2_btn.setText(mQuestions.getChoice2(num));
        ans3_btn.setText(mQuestions.getChoice3(num));
        ans4_btn.setText(mQuestions.getChoice4(num));


        mAnswer = mQuestions.getCorrectAnswer(num);
        resetButtons();

        }

        public void resetButtons(){
            ans1_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.default_btn);
            ans2_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.default_btn);
            ans3_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.default_btn);
            ans4_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.default_btn);
        }

    //...//


    //Other Functions
        private void gameOver(){
            uScore -=5;

            Toast.makeText(Game.this,"Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (uScore < 0){
            uScore = 0;
            score.setText("0");
        }
            score.setText("Score: "+ String.valueOf(uScore));
            myRef.child("users").child(userId).child("eScore").setValue(uScore);
            if (ans1_btn.getText()  != mAnswer){
                ans1_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wrong_btn);
            }else if (ans2_btn.getText()!=mAnswer){
                ans2_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wrong_btn);
            }else if (ans3_btn.getText()!=mAnswer) {
                ans3_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wrong_btn);
            }else if (ans4_btn.getText()!=mAnswer) {
                ans4_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wrong_btn);
            }
            resetButtons();
           updateQuestion(r.nextInt(mQuestionsLength));
        }

    //...//





        }
```

Comment: So you want to see if you answered ok or not and then reset the buttons with a new question?

Comment: It already verifies if It got the correct answer so all i need is a way to get the button to turn green when correct or red when incorect then on question refresh the buttons also refresh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here

```
ans1_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.corect_btn);
                    resetButtons();
                    updateQuestion(r.nextInt(mQuestionsLength));
```

and all of the ansX_btn what you want to do is something like this,to let the user know when the answer is correct or incorrect.

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    resetButtons();
                    updateQuestion(r.nextInt(mQuestionsLength));
                }
            }, 5000);
```